# How to flip the mouse cursor in VS Code when hovering over the line number/gutter?

Tags: visual-studio-code, accessibility, vscode-extensions

I'd like to have the mouse cursor horizontally flipped/mirrored when hovering over the line number in VS Code on Windows. Editors like Notepad++ and full Visual Studio do this, and it helps usability for rapid line selection.

[image: 1]

I see comments from a few years ago online saying that VS Code supports this (e.g.  https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/40382/why-does-the-mouse-cursor-switch-direction-over-line-numbers-in-programming-ides#comment190852_40384), but I can't figure out how to enable it, so I'm assuming they removed support. From what I can tell, all the settings which mention "cursor" have to do with text cursors, i.e. carets, not mouse cursors.

Is there a way to enable this? If not, is this something VS Code exposes for extensions to modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse pointer used to flip when hovering over line numbers. But, its behaviour was changed in version 1.42 as explained [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90707#issuecomment-586378954)

> This is intentional change in 1.42 see [#85176](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85176) because there is not native way to provide "flipped" cursor except putting it as image which won't match system cursor.

> Is there a way to enable this? If not, is this something VS Code exposes for extensions to modify?

It might be possible to enable the behaviour or to create an extension by using the old css code which can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/ff7e302ad6c3ce70e2546ef136b1bf3163bcdeef/src/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/lineNumbers/lineNumbers.css). Maybe yourself or another menber can show you the steps to use it.